# Nesting promises with q-io

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, promise, q

I'm trying to make sense of the idea that promises that return another promise become the value of the return.  That's what I read in the Q docs on the wiki.  https://github.com/kriskowal/q#tutorial

Its the ideal situation, as I'm using q-io/http which uses a promise to make the request.  However, the function returns the value of the body in a new promise.

Rather than nesting the rest of my code inside my first function.  I want to be notified when the nested promise is complete.  However, because of scope, I can't seem to do it.  But I keep reading that my outer function should become the value of the inner promise.  Am I missing something?

Ex.

```
module.exports = function (obj) {
  var getFiles = HTTP.request(obj);

  getFiles
   .then(function(res) {
      return res.body.read()
    });
  return getFiles;
};
```

I want to be notified when res.body.read() fulfills its promise using Q.all(), but I don't know how to get that value.  I feel like getFiles should become that inner promise.  Right?

Comment: Try returning the output of `getFiles.then()` from the outer function.

Comment: Thanks Beetroot-Beetroot, your answer will definitely work in this situation too.

Comment: Adam, it's the same solution as Bergi's. To keep it short, I left out the simplification. As you can see, method chaining makes the assignment to `getFiles` is unnecessary.

Comment: Gotcha.  Makes perfect sense.  Thanks again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I feel like getFiles should become that inner promise. Right?

No. A promise won't change it's value. However, the `.then` method does return a new promise that will be resolved with the result of the "inner promise" `read` method (which will be called when `getFiles` is resolved).

You can shorten your code to

```
module.exports = function (obj) {
  return HTTP.request(obj).then(function(res) {
    return res.body.read()
  });
};
```

Comment: Still trying to process this, but it works perfect.  Thanks Bergi.